# How to Take two SQL queries of a column of substrings to search database using the appended result of the other

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I have two select statements that both contain a column of substrings that derived from a database table. They are substrings derived from a varchar that should be an XML, but were saved as varcars because they could be not well-formed and potentially invalid.

I am trying to take the table that results in the 1st query, a list of 50 Varchars, and search the database using the 2nd query. I could get from 0 to n SQLRelatesMessageID sets from each SQLmessageID if I use each row in the first query and append a string to get the  node ("z4480" is an example here).

I have tried a cursor implementation but the performance detered me from finishing it. Join doesn't work if you try giving the substring column with an as alias. What steps should I do to get the overall list of SQLRelatesMessageIDs. My goal is to get all MessageLogId (3 in picture) given a NCPDPID.

I am using SQL Server Manager 2012.

```
--1--Recieves a list based on a given NCPDPID node Value
select substring(m.message, charindex('<MessageID>', m.message)+11, charindex('</MessageID>', m.message)-charindex('<MessageID>', m.message)-11) as 
 SQLmessageID from messagelog m where message like '%<NCPDPID>'+'1234567'+'</NCPDPID>%' 

--2--Selects messageID from top select and searches RelatesToMessageID node

select substring(r.message, charindex('<RelatesToMessageID>', r.message)+20,   charindex('</RelatesToMessageID>', r.message)-charindex('<RelatesToMessageID>',  r.message)-20) as SQLRelatesMessageID, * from messagelog r 
where message like ('%<RelatesToMessageID>'+'z4480'+'</RelatesToMessageID>%')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works for this answer.

```
---main
SELECT * FROM 
  (
 select substring(m.message, charindex('<MessageID>', m.message)+11,  charindex('</MessageID>', m.message)-charindex('<MessageID>', m.message)-11) as  SQLmessageID from messagelog m 
where message like '%<NCPDPID>1234567</NCPDPID>%' and dateTime > '3/01/2016'
 ) a JOIN 
 (
select 
  substring(r.message, charindex('<RelatesToMessageID>', r.message)+20,  charindex('</RelatesToMessageID>', r.message)-charindex('<RelatesToMessageID>',  r.message)-20) as SQLRelatesMessageID, 
  message, 
  messagelogid from messagelog r
 where 
  dateTime > '3/01/2016' AND 
  message LIKE ('%<RelatesToMessageID>%</RelatesToMessageID>%') 
  ) b ON b.SQLRelatesMessageID = a.SQLmessageID
```